# How to use bundled json in my android application?

Tags: android, json

I need to use bundled json in my application.So i added my json file under assets folder.How to write code for using this ?Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you first need to read your json from asset folder

```
    InputStream is = appContext.getAssets().open("myJson.json");
int size = is.available();
buffer = new byte[size];
is.read(buffer);
is.close();
String bufferString = new String(buffer);
```

and then you can do

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(bufferString);
```

and now `obj` contain your `json`.